# Cordova project build error

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, native, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a simple Cordova application with visual studio when I get the following error. I also get this when I try to run my project with all emulators but Ripple (ripple works fine and I get correct results). I think there is a problem with one of toolchain components used with cordova but can't find which one. 
Erros include *Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.*

```html
1>------ Build started: Project: Hi, Configuration: Release Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: E:\Program Files\Visual Studio 2015\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.37
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.0.0 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\bld\Android\Release
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\bin\Android\Release
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Release
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Release
1>  ------    projectName: Hi
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Reza\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.3.1
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins
1>  No differences found between project and android platform. Continuing...
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Found "merges" for android platform. Copying over existing "www" files.
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "Hi"
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myapp2d120c"
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  updated project successfully
1>  Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\bin\Android\Release\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Release
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --release
1>  Executing "before_compile"  hook for all plugins.
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
1>  Reading build config file: C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\build.json
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build warning : Warning: 'keystore' and 'alias' need to be specified to generate a signed archive.
1>MDAVSCLI : warning : 'keystore' and 'alias' need to be specified to generate a signed archive.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
1>  Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
1>  java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
1>   at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:599)
1>   at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:599)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
1>   at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
1>   at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
1>   at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
1>   at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
1>   at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
1>   at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:109)
1>   at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:109)
1>
1>  BUILD FAILED
1>
1>  Total time: 1.316 secs
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:98)
1>   at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:98)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
1>   at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
1>   at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
1>   at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
1>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
1>   at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
1>   at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
1>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
1>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
1>   at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
1>   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
1>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
1>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
1>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
1>   at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
1>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
1>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
1>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
1>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
1>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Where:
1>  * Where:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Script 'C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64
1>  Script 'C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>  * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
1>  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
1>  > No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>  * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>  ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildRelease -b "C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildRelease -b "C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildRelease -b "C:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hi - Copy\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll all the way down, a quite clear error message appears: `No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.`

So to resolve this error, open the Android SDK Manager and install `Android SDK Build-tools` (In the `tools` folder)

Comment: Android SDK manager displays build tools, platform tools and sdk tools in tools folder when opened.

Answer (score 0):

is can have several erros, i have a same issue, and the problem was that have dot in android-versionCode, 

 like:  `android-versionCode="10001.1"`